# Output every letter in a span with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this:

```
var letter = 'abcd';
var split = letter.split("");
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    html += split[i];
    $('<span/>')
        .data('letter', letter)
        .data('match-count', bins[letter] || 0)   
        .html(letter)
        .appendTo(alphabet);
}
```

This outputs letter like this:

```
<span>abcd</span>
<span>abcd</span>
<span>abcd</span>
<span>abcd</span>
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
<span>a</span>
<span>b</span>
<span>c</span>
<span>d</span>
```

Can anybody try to help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In your for-loop, you assign the HTML text of the `letter` variable to the `<span>` element. If you want to add the individual letters here, you won't get it, since you already split them in the `split` variable (and `letter` is the full string).

Instead, you could use

```js
 .html(split[i])
```

But it seems like the letter is referenced in other places.

This is also a good opportunity to review good variable naming practices. `letter` implies one character, but is assigned `'abcd'`. Later in the for-loop, you intended to assign a single character, but the `letter` variable name was misleading.

After some refactoring:

```js
var letters = 'abcd';
var split = letters.split("");
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    html += split[i];
    letter = split[i];
    $('<span/>')
        .data('letter', letter)
        .data('match-count', bins[letter] || 0)   
        .html(letter)
        .appendTo(alphabet);
}
```

I'm not sure what your intending with the `html` variable, but if you want it to hold the whole string, you don't need to rebuild it with the `html += split[i];` inside the loop. You can simplify by assigning it in the declaration: `var html = letters;`

@Yevgren shows a more modern approach to what you're attempting (keep in mind it's not fully supported in all browsers (e.g. Internet Explorer 11)).